# chrome extension setPopup is not propagated immediately

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on chrome extension and I want to have 2 pages one main popup and then on click on specific button I want to replace it with other one(some settings page) so far I managed to change it using

```
chrome.action.setPopup({ popup: "settings.html" })
```

but problem is in fact that it's not immediately propagated, I have to click on extension to close it and click again to open it to be able to see settings page, did I missed something or what is the preferred way in such case?

Comment: Have the popup itself navigate to another URL. `setPopup` exists to configure what page opens when you click the button.

Comment: `location.href = 'newpopup.html'` inside the popup page.

Comment: actually this what I use works, but I have to reopen extension, I want to propagate change/new page immediately

Comment: @CherryDT do not get this